# Getting a true or false result testing if a list has 4 consecutive numbers in multiple directions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a list and I want to test for a positive result of 4 or more in a row in any directions (I am testing for B and E)
e.g.:

```
List = [N, N, B, N, N, E, B, E, N,
        N, E, B, N, E, E, E, B, N,
        N, N, N, N, N, E, B, E, N,
        N, E, B, N, E, E, E, B, N]
```

It is longer but you get the point,
anyway I would want that to return as True for `E` as there are four in a row for `E` but no for `B`. I also want to test for diagonal as well but I am struggling to work out how to even attempt this as it is.
I have no example code because I don't know how to attack this problem.
Let me know if I need to explain differently.

Comment: You have represented the list as four rows with nine columns  How did you choose that? Why not twelve rows of three columns? What if the list has as many as forty-eight items or  as few as fifteen?

Comment: it cannot be more then 10 rows. honestly it would probably better for for there to be 7 columns with 6 in each column, but i thought there would be some algorithmic way to work it out that i could implement into multiple different situations.

Comment: Your list does not have any rows or columns (or diagonals, for the matter). It is a list of 36 values. If you want a "matrix-style" data structure, you must use a list of lists. What have you tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Each item has an index. You need to determine the indices and offsets for the other three items you want to compare - the indices/offset for the items that appear in a column or a diagonal will differ depending on how you *chop up* the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier if we can represent this data as a grid structure with x, y coordinates for each point. We can use a class to set the data up in this way. The class needs to know how wide you want the grid to be in order to do this. To find a sequence of items, we can iterate through the rows and columns, and each time we find a match for the item, we check that the adjacent squares in each direction also contain the same item.

```
class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, data, width):
        self.data = data
        self.width = width
        self.height = len(L) / width

    def get(self, x, y):
        """ Find the item in the grid at the given coordinates """
        if 0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height:
            return self.data[y * self.width + x]

    def find_sequence(self, item, times):
        """ Check for a sequence of item occuring at least the specified 
        number of times. Checks right, down, down-right, and down-left. """

        for y in range(self.height):
            for x in range(self.width):
                # if we find the item at x, y...
                if self.get(x, y) == item:
                    # ... then look at adjacent items in each direction
                    for dx, dy in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (-1, 1)]:
                        if all(self.get(x + i*dx, y + i*dy) == item 
                               for i in range(1, times)):
                            return True
        return False

N, B, E = "N", "B", "E"
data = [N, N, B, N, N, E, B, E, N,
        N, E, B, N, E, E, E, B, N,
        N, N, N, N, N, E, B, E, N,
        N, E, B, N, E, E, E, B, N]
grid = Grid(data, width=9)
grid.get(3, 3)   # N
grid.find_sequence(B, 4)  # False
grid.find_sequence(N, 4)  # True
grid.find_sequence(E, 4)  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
List = [N, N, B, N, N, E, B, E, N,
        N, E, B, N, E, E, E, B, N,
        N, N, N, N, N, E, B, E, N,
        N, E, B, N, E, E, E, B, N]

limit = 4

flag = False

oldValue = ''
newValue = ''

counter = 0

for i in range(0, len(List)):
  newValue = List[i]

  if (newValue == oldValue):
    counter += 1

  oldValue = newValue

  if (counter >= 4):
    flag = True
    break


print 'Result is' + str(flag)
```

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We discourage answers to the questions that do not demonstrate any effort.

Comment: Honestly I just answered because I was bored. But you are completely right.